# Mongoose is returning empty array while fetching data from MongoDb Atlas. Why?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

**App.js file->Connection is established successfully, but in find() callback,data is empty[]**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Users = require('./users');
    const app = express();
    mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://sanjeev:**pass**@cluster0.ckywrym.mongodb.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority/sanjeevDb",
        {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        }).then(() => console.log("connection established successfully"));
```

Within find callback I am getting empty array in data

```
    Users.find({}, (error, data) => {
        if (error)
            console.log("Error: ", error);
            console.log(data)
         });
```

**users.js - defining the schema as same on mongoDb Atlas**

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        name: String,
        email: String,
        country: String
    });
    
    module.exports= mongoose.model('userCollect', userSchema);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90wTg.jpg)

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection

Answer (score 0):

you are logging data even when there is error. do this

```
Users.find({}, (err, data) => { 
if (err){
console.log(err);
} else {
console.log(data);
})
```

or

```
//with async (recommended)
try {
const users = await Users.find({});
console.log(users);
} catch (err) {
console.log(err);
}
```